# I think I saw William with one

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> As noun, my foes find me traumatic
>
> (**Balls!** they say - quite cinematic).
>
> As verb, my use ain't systematic;
>
> but phrasal, my limbs go erratic.

Very specific `knowlege`, thus probably unhelpful, tip (but I couldn't resist):

> Why did they make ages 5 worse than 4. I can't be taking my boots on and off!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you a

> Flail?

Because

> as a noun, you are a primitive weapon, such as a morning star
>  as a verb, you are waving your arms around erratically
>  and in a phrase "flailing your arms" your limbs move erratically

However,

> I can't tie it in with the title (unless an ancient William is associated with the weapon, which I couldn't find) or the tip.

Comment: Correct! Want to specifically explain the "Balls" part, loved that one! Also, Wallace...